# How can I capture a stack trace on the QA computers

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, visual-c++

I am writing a Qt/C++ application, up until this month I have been using Mingw for compiling and drmingw for getting the stack trace from the QA people.

However I recently converted over to MSVC++ 9 so that I can use the phonon framework.

The downside is that now the stack traces from drmingw are useless.  What do others use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dr Watson to catch unhandled exceptions and generate a dump file.
The dump can then be opened in Visual Studio or WinDBG to see the stack of all threads, as long as you have the symbol files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265791.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the call stack yourself, you can use [dbghelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679267(VS.85).aspx). You can find good example code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx).